# Compare much array with one array

Tags: php, arrays

Good morning,

I need to compare an all row of DB with an array, example:

**DB**

```
VALUE 1 - VALUE 2 - VALUE 3
1         2         3
```

**What i try (PHP)**

```
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'namedb';
$db = new MySQLi($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
$sql=$db->query("SELECT * from numbers");



$all =array('1' => '6',
             '2' =>'32',
             '3' => '50'

);


while($res=$sql->fetch_array()){
$value1=$res['value1'];
$value2=$res['value2'];
$value3=$res['value3'];

$arraydb=array('1' => $value1,
              '2' =>$value2,
              '3' => $value3,

);

}
if ($all != $arraydb){
print_r($all);  

}else{
    echo 'exist in db';

}
```

I take all value from DB and put in the array then compare it with a 1 static array.
the problem that if I put the code to compare the values ​​from the database in the while it will always write to me until it finds one the same.
Instead, I would like that by comparing all the values ​​if there is even just one write me "exists in the DB" instead if comparing them it finds nothing write me the number

---

edit:
@Luuk (if comparing them it finds nothing write me the number, It is not clear which number you are referring to)
I need to compare all DB row with a single array

@Dilek
I can't use `WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)` because i have 3 label in DB(value1-value2-value3) for example 1 - 2 - 3 and my array have (3-2-1) so if i compare the two array doesn't match. i need to compare all row db if value don't match print just one time the single array else "exist in db"

@Slepic (Remove the print_r line if you dont want the numbers printed. Anyway, your code has bigger issues... )
I need to print the value only if is all DB doesn't match with single array (the code will not upload online so don't worry for DB security)

@mitkosoft
The `$arraydb` contain value from DB like my example:

```
$arraydb=array('1' => '1',
              '2' => '2',
              '3' => '3',
);
```

Comment: `if comparing them it finds nothing write me the number`, It is not clear which number you are referring to.

Comment: just get the entire table and create an array output of it. Then loop through the ids checking the outputs. The other thing you can do is build the query to include all the questions you need so you only query once and then compare arrays using php array_diff probably! Example : Query the database ONCE. SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4) ($all_ids) and iterate through the results. Or create create an array from result of dB and compare them $array[] == $row;

Comment: Remove the print_r line if you dont want the numbers printed. Anyway, your code has bigger issues...

Comment: did you have checked what do you produce in `$arraydb` after the `while`? could you show us what's inside?

Comment: answer to all comment in my edit

Comment: Possibile solution is create a variable in the whil,  like if match = 1 else 0 and print array. I will try and comment if work

Comment: Not work.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my solution alone, post for community:

```
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'namedb';
$db = new MySQLi($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * from numbers");

$all = array(
    '1' => '6',
    '2' => '32',
    '3' => '50'

);

while ($res = $sql->fetch_array()) {
    $value1 = $res['value1'];
    $value2 = $res['value2'];
    $value3 = $res['value3'];

    $arraydb = array(
        '1' => $value1,
        '2' => $value2,
        '3' => $value3,

    );
    $result = array_diff($all, $arraydb);
    $count = $sql->num_rows;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        if (empty($result)) {
            echo 'exist in db';
            exit;
        } else {
            $doesntmatch = '1';
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
if ($doesntmatch = '1') {
    print_r($all);
}
```

So now if `$all` array and `$arraydb` is empty with function `array_diff`(all value is matched) the FOR will exit and echo *'exist in db'* else will print `$all`